# $watch waiting too long to recognize a change

Tags: angularjs

This is some logic in a controller:

```
function newGame(){

     $scope.gameOver = true;

      $timeout(function(){

       //do stuff

       $scope.gameOver = false;

      }, 3000);

}
```

In a directive I have:

```
scope.$watch(scope.gameOver,function(){ console.log("changed!", scope.gameOver);})
```

I'd like to do something based on scope.gameOver. I use the timeout function to give the game 3 seconds of time where gameOver = true. However, watch does nothing during those 3 seconds and instead fires off at the end of those 3 seconds where scope.gameOver has already been turned back into false.

What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$watch` callback function will be invoked at least once when the `$watch` is set up, irrespective of whether or not your `scope.gameOver` variable changes.

This is pointed out in the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch):

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the `listener` fn is called asynchronously (via `$evalAsync`) to initialize the watcher.

I think you may be running into unexpected behaviour because you are specifying to `$watch` a primitive value instead of a reference to the variable holding the value of interest.

In other words,

```
scope.$watch(scope.gameOver, function() { ... });
```

as you have specified, would be the same as,

```
scope.$watch(true, function() { ... });
```

which obviously will not do anything productive.

Instead, prefer specifying your `$watch` using a function to return a reference to `scope.gameOver` or alternatively take advantage of how the variable to `$watch` can be an Angular expression:

```
// Function to return reference to the variable to watch
scope.$watch(function() { return scope.gameOver; }, function() { ... });

// Expression for Angular to evaluate
scope.$watch('gameOver', function() { ... });
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The value vs reference was it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Watch will be triggered only when the watch parameter changes. So in your code the  **$scope.gameOver**
changes only at the end of 3 seconds and hence the watch is triggered.